# Best way to compare sha1 hashes for equality

Tags: c++, hash, equality, memcmp

I want to compare two sha1 hashes for equality. What could be the most efficient way to do this? Currently, I am trying using memcmp. Thanks.

Comment: The real question should be: Why bother?  Do you really *need* something that is faster than your current solution?  I doubt that comparing SHA1s is the bottle neck in your application.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer excellent point

Comment: I totally agree with Ferdinand and what you are trying to do is called 'premature optimization' which should be avoided...

Comment: Well.. @FredOverflow solution (is_same_sha1) seems to be faster than memcmp and it's not negligible. Thanks for it. I am just trying to see if I can make it even faster. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Did you just measure the hash comparisons, or did you measure the whole program performance? Because actually *computing* the hashes beforehand is likely to be several orders of magnitude slower, so it wouldn't matter at all how efficient the comparison is.

Comment: @FredOverflow I measured performance for whole program and it turns out to be faster than memcmp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since you already know at compile-time how large the blocks are, you could do this:

```
#include <cstdint>

bool is_same_sha1(const char* p, const char* q)
{
    const std::uint32_t* a = (const std::uint32_t*)p;
    const std::uint32_t* b = (const std::uint32_t*)q;
    return a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1] && a[2] == b[2]
        && a[3] == b[3] && a[4] == b[4];
}
```

But don't take my advice blindly, you should **measure** any custom solution against the `memcmp` solution and only use it if it gives you a significant performance advantage. I wouldn't even be surprised if `memcmp` was still faster because it did something extremely clever and dirty.

Comment: This seems like a good solution. It's faster than memcmp for my use. Thanks. Though I have to see if std::equal makes any difference.

Comment: This may fail if the buffers aren't aligned correctly.  (It's also formally undefined behavior, but it is clear that the intent is for it to work _if_ external constraints such as alignment are met, and it would be a very poor implementation where it didn't.)

Comment: Also, of course, `uint32_t` might not be available.  (In the end, it depends on your portability constraints.  `uint32_t` _will_ be available under Windows and under Posix compliant systems.  And there are an awful lot of applications where that's portable enough.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Could you please elaborate? Where does the buffer alignment comes into picture here?

Comment: @polapts: in C and C++, types may have alignment requirements, meaning that the address of a pointer to that type *must* be divisible by the required alignment. It's common for the alignment requirement of `uint32_t` to be `4`. So, if `p` or `q` happen not to be 4-aligned, then it's undefined behavior to cast them to `uint32_t*`. For example if I write `const char *foo == "11..1"`, with 21 digits in there, then `is_same_sha1(foo, foo+1)` is UB on an implementation that requires 4-alignment for `uint32_t`, since `foo` and `foo+1` can't both be 4-aligned.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with `memcmp()`? You have to compare every byte of both hashes; `memcmp()` will quickly fail on the first difference it finds; and `memcmp()` can be written by the library authors to work in chunk sizes that are good choices for the platform.

Comment: I would expect `std::equal` to be faster than `memcpy`; the compiler generates it for the precise type involved, and can possibly even take into account things like alignment.  (Of course, `memcpy` is likely just a `#define` for something like `__builtin_memcpy`, so that the compiler can do similar optimizations.)

Comment: True, but your advice to align on boundaries is definitely worth while; if they aligned on 32 byte blocks, it might be a single SSE-something instruction to check them...

Comment: @sarnold Is there an SSE instruction that compares exactly 160 bits? :) You would probably have to overread from memory (dangerous?) and then mask off the extra bits.

Comment: @Fred: A single op might be optimistic, but you presumably could do it as a 128 and a 32 *if* you had the right alignment. Unfortunately, checking the alignment might well take longer than unconditionally doing it in smaller chunks.

Comment: @Fred: I was thinking of zeroing the next twelve bytes so they do not influence the comparison. I did get a little overzealous and assume that newer SSE* instructions might introduce 256 bit comparison routines, but you're right: it looks like most of the CPU's comparison instructions are intended for 128 bit blocks at most. Though [SSE 4.2 introduced some variable-length string comparison routines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4.2#SSE4.2), it might be a little while before libraries include them.

Answer (score 2):

`std::equal` would seem the best bet, but `memcmp` would also work.
With regards to efficiency, it will depend on the implementation, but
also (possibly) how the data is defined and represented.